# Android - Work on network with volley?

Tags: android, android-volley, android-networking

For example I am connecting to a `service`(url) with `volley` for get a message(json) .This service often get to me a message(json) for example per 2 days or 1 hours or any other time get me a message(json).

My problem is here : How I can listen to service when coming message(json),connect to service then get message(json) ?

I inserted my connection to service(url) in a thread for check per 1 hour .But this principle is not.

use from `Thread` or `extend Service` for check coming message(json) this principle is not.

I can't use from FireBase I need to another way.

**(I am connecting a webservice with volley that get me a json ,I need that each time the message(json) came I get the json .I need to call volley automatically each time the message(json) came.)**

What can I do ?

Comment: I am not sure I understood your question correctly, but as far as I know with volley you don't need to handle your own threads, since all that is done for you already.
Are you trying to implement some kind of polling mechanism?

Comment: Hi Jo Jo, I apparently cannot figure out what you're trying to do. Can you please explain a bit more.
Are you trying to poll a web service every hour or so?
Thank you.

Comment: I am connecting a webservice with volley that get me a json ,I need that each time the message(json) came I get the json .I need to call volley automatically each time the message(json) came.

Comment: Why do you want to call volley again when the response comes? Do you want to call another link when the response comes from volley? Or do you want to perform some operation when volley downloads completely.

Comment: @ abbas.I am checking my url per 1 hours that if I have an json message I get it but I don't like use from this way I need that when i had json message connect to url (for connect to url I should use from volley )